# Loading sidebar blocks based on post type

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, custom-post-type, fishpig

I'm using the Fishpig WordPress extension for Magento (with the CPT extension) and I can't seem to figure out how to load sidebar blocks based on the type of the current post. I want to load a particular block only if:

- I'm viewing a single post with the type `recipe`
- I'm viewing the archive for the type `recipe`
- I'm viewing the term page for the custom taxonomy `recipe_category`

For the single post view, I added the block in my local.xml like this:

```
<wordpress_post_view>
    <reference name="right">
        <remove name="wordpress.widget.categories" />
        <block type="wordpress/sidebar_widget_categories" name="wordpress.widget.recipe_categories" before="-" as="recipe_categories" template="wordpress/sidebar/widget/categories.phtml">
            <action method="setTitle"><title>Recipe Categories</title></action>
            <action method="setTaxonomy"><title>recipe_category</title></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</wordpress_post_view>
```

That's working fine, I just need to figure out how to restrict it to display only for the `recipe` post type. Same goes for the `recipe` archive and the `recipe_category` taxonomy term archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above poster is correct that using layout handles is a good way to do this (although the wordpress_post_view_POSTTYPE layout handle already exists so there is no need to create it via an observer) but I decided that this approach would probably be too technical for a large portion of users.

In reaction to this, I have just released version 3.1.1.25 of [Magento WordPress Integration](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/) that adds support for the [Custom Sidebars](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-sidebars/) plugin. This plugin allows you to create extra sidebars in the WordPress Admin and trigger them to display based on things such as the post type, the archive type (category, date, homepage, search etc) as well as specify different sidebars for each specific post. This can all be done via the WordPress Admin > Widgets page.

To add this functionality, upgrade the extension to the latest version and then install the Custom Sidebars plugin in the WordPress Admin. You will then be able to create custom sidebars without touching any code.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to cobble together a solution by checking the post type in the `wordpress/sidebar/widget/categories.phtml` template file. Still interested in a cleaner solution.

```
$post_type = 'post';
if( $post = Mage::registry('wordpress_post') ) {
    $post_type = $post->getPostType();
} elseif( $type = Mage::registry('wordpress_post_type') ) {
    $post_type = $type->getPostType();
} elseif( $term = Mage::registry('wordpress_term') ) {
    $post_type = $term->getTaxonomy() == 'recipe_category' ? 'recipe' : 'post';
}

if( $post_type == 'recipe' ) {
    $this->setTaxonomy('recipe_category');
    $this->setTitle('Recipe Categories');
}

$categories = $this->getCategories();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BenTideswell for alerting us to the fact that this extension already provides an appropriate layout handle that can be used for this purpose, so we don’t need to create another one. We only need to do a couple of [layout XML updates](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/) that target the appropriate post type:

```
<wordpress_post_view>
    <reference name="right">
        <remove name="wordpress.widget.categories"/>
    </reference>
</wordpress_post_view>

<wordpress_post_view_recipe>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="wordpress/sidebar_widget_categories" name="wordpress.widget.recipe_categories" before="-" as="recipe_categories" template="wordpress/sidebar/widget/categories.phtml">
            <action method="setTitle"><title>Recipe Categories</title></action>
            <action method="setTaxonomy"><title>recipe_category</title></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</wordpress_post_view_recipe>
```

Comment: At the time of writing, this was the best solution. As it's probably too complex for most users, I've updated the extension and added support for the Custom Sidebars plugin, allowing you to create sidebars automatically via the WordPress Admin.

Comment: @BenTideswell - Thanks for updating your extension to make it easier for users to accomplish this. I updated my answer to show just the layout update XML concept and target the existing handle.